# How to use Axios in Nest.js to POST params request?

Tags: axios, nestjs, mikro-orm

I am beginner in NestJS and I would like to ask question on how to use Axios in NestJs. But the problem is I keep getting error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

I have created an API POST `http://localhost:3000/api/create` in NestJS and my raw request

**Raw input**

```
{
    "id":1, 
    "date":"2022-06-28", 
    "roster":[
        {
            "startDate":"2022-06-27",
            "weekDay":1,
            "session":1,
            "sTime":"08:00:00",
            "eTime":"10:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Postman request images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g1tR.jpg)

My goal is in **create.service.ts** file, I want pass the value that I receive in postman and add all values into new API link `https://create.com/api/index.php?id=&date=&roster=[]`.

**Expected output** : `https://create.com/api/index.php?id=1&date=2022-06-27&roster=[{"startDate":"2022-06-27","weekDay":1,"session":1,"sTime":"08:00:00","eTime":"10:00:00"}]`

But I receive an error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` when I submit my post request

**create.service.ts**

```
import { HttpException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import axios from 'axios';
import { CreateValidator } from './create.validator';

@Injectable()
export class CreateService {
    constructor() { }

    async create(query: CreateValidator) { 
        return axios.post(`https://create.com/api/index.php?`, null, { params: query })
            .then()
            .catch(err => {
                throw new HttpException(err.response?.data ?? err.response?.statusText ?? 'Unexpected error.', err.response?.status ?? 400);
        }); 

    } 
}
```

**create.controller.ts**

```
import { Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiConsumes, ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { BaseController } from '../base/base.controller';
import { CreateService } from './create.service';
import { CreateValidator } from './create.validator';
@ApiTags('New : Create ')
export class CreateController extends BaseController {
    constructor(
        private readonly createService: CreateService,
    ) {
        super();
    }

    @Post('api/create')
    @ApiConsumes('application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    async create(@Body() body: CreateValidator) {
        const result = await this.createService.create(body);
        return {result,};
    }
}
```

**create.validator.ts**

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsNotEmpty, isString } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateValidator {
    @ApiProperty({type: Number,required: true,})
    id: number;

    @ApiProperty({type: String,required: true,})
    date: Date; 

    @ApiProperty({type: [Object],})
    @Transform((input) => isString(input.value) ? JSON.parse(input.value) : input.value)
    @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'IsNotEmpty' })
    roster: Array<{
        startDate: Date;
        weekDay: number; 
        s_time: string;
        e_time: string;
    }>;
}
```

My current coding as below

Comment: Where did your `validatorPipeline` setup and how did you do it

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need to change `@ApiProperty({ type : [Object]})` into `@ApiProperty({ type : Object })` in my validator file.

**create.validator.ts**

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsNotEmpty, isString } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateValidator {
    @ApiProperty({type: Number,required: true,})
    id: number;

    @ApiProperty({type: String,required: true,})
    date: Date; 

    @ApiProperty({type: Object,})
    @Transform((input) => isString(input.value) ? JSON.parse(input.value) : input.value)
    @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'IsNotEmpty' })
    roster: Array<{
        startDate: Date;
        weekDay: number; 
        s_time: string;
        e_time: string;
    }>;
}
```

Now it's working fine.

Thanks.